# Why would I be getting an illegal token?

Tags: jquery

The following is giving me an illegal token error message:

```
$('.navigation3').click(function(event) {
    var $nav3 = $(this),
        $dd = $nav3.next('.dropdown');

    $nav3.toggleClass('active');

    var leftoffset = $dd.width() - $nav3.width();

    var offset = 20,
        offsettop = $nav3.offset().top + $nav3.height() + offset,
        offsetleft = $nav3.offset().left-leftoffset ;


    $dd.css({
        top: offsettop,
        left: offsetleft
    });

    $nav3.hasClass('active') ? $dd.show() : $dd.hide();
});​
```

It's happening on the last `});`.  Any idea why?

Comment: This code looks fine. But maybe there is something else before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. There maybe some invisible character which happens sometimes sitting in the code when copying and pasting the code. Try deleting all invisible characters (including whitespace) around that area, and try again.

**Update**

There was a unwanted character sitting at the end of the script. I cleaned the code and try it now, it should work

```
$('.navigation3').click(function(event) {
    var $nav3 = $(this),
        $dd = $nav3.next('.dropdown');

    $nav3.toggleClass('active');

    var leftoffset = $dd.width() - $nav3.width();

    var offset = 20,
        offsettop = $nav3.offset().top + $nav3.height() + offset,
        offsetleft = $nav3.offset().left-leftoffset ;


    $dd.css({
        top: offsettop,
        left: offsetleft
    });

    $nav3.hasClass('active') ? $dd.show() : $dd.hide();
});
```

Comment: Where exactly was that unwanted character and how did you get rid of it.  I keep getting this issue.

Comment: at the end of `});`. When i checked in notepad++ editor it was like `});?`

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator evaluates the expression and returns a value that is expected to be assigned.

A simple if/else statement instead of a ternary operator would do the trick